# values of static variables not changing by user input java

Tags: java, variables, static, event-handling, static-methods

I'm working on a program that plots a mathematical expression like x^2 .
the way it works is that the user will enter the range of x (like -10 to 10 ) and then a graph from that range will be drawn.
the method by which the graph is drawn looks like this :

```
            Plotter plotterGUI = new Plotter(minX, maxX, frequency, eqFile);
```

this line (in plotter class) requires me to make minX and maxX fields as static .

[link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8kbtp1vc48o9xz9/AAAon9GJ3foUpAEXT3G-BZlia?dl=0) for the whole code (main class is plotter).

and this is the looks of the program:
[image]
The problem is that when user fills two field for minX and maxX ,then clicks on the set Min/Max button; but , the values of these two field does not change in the graph panel (as you can see in picture it still draws in -10 to 10 range) .
this the code for set button's event handler:

```
btnSetMinmax.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            maxInput = maxxField.getText();
            minInput = minxField.getText();

            maxX = Double.parseDouble(maxInput);
            minX = Double.parseDouble(minInput);

            playSlider.setMaximum((int) maxX);
            playSlider.setMinimum((int) minX);
            playSlider.setValue((int) minX);

        }
    });
```

from what I've read on stack overflow I should be able to change static variables' values so why the values doesn't change in here ?

Update : when I debug the code the program stops at :

```
maxInput = maxxField.getText();
minInput = minxField.getText();
```

and says source not found.

Comment: Perhaps you just need to repaint the gui component. This is typical.

Comment: @Atuos where exactly should I put repaint() ? 
adding it to the event handler didn't solve the problem

Comment: To be clear, this is speculation. I do not know how your plotter works. But if I am right you should tell the plotter to repaint itself in the action listener after all the data is set.

Comment: @Atuos but that doesn't work .
when I debug the program  the code stops at     
      maxInput = maxxField.getText();
      minInput = minxField.getText();
and tells source not found

Comment: Are you sure the values are not changing? Just do System.out.println("Max = " + maxX + "Min = " + minX); Your debugger not finding the source does not matter, you do not need to see how parseDouble() works.

Comment: @Atuos that's what I'm trying to do by adding sysouts after each line but after the first line :
            maxInput = maxxField.getText();
debugger stops and show source not found message

Comment: Then don't use the debugger, just run the program normally.

Comment: @Atuos the reason I use debugger is because it doesn't work normally

Comment: What doesn't work normally? I thought your problem was that your graph doesn't update when you give new values... I think you just need to call graph.repaint() at the end of your action listener.

Comment: let me guess - when you change values in the code   `  // Grapher params
     double maxX = 10;
    static double minX = -10;` it works. But from input field on UI it does not, right?

Comment: the code on dropbox is actually a piece of good old procedural programming, so everything is effectively static (just a remark). I don't see any setters in your Graph class and I'm not sure it would accept any changes to Graph.minX / Graph.maxX. Try re-drawing your plot completely with createNewGraph(...) after you set up new min/max values for X.

Comment: @harshtuna your are exactly right 
so you think I should opt out of changing those values?
should make a new method ?
can you be more specific about it?

Comment: maybe invoke createNewGraph(...) after the user defined new boundaries

Comment: @harshtuna I'm sorry I still don't understand why should I invoke create new graph as it is invoked already and how can I change those values by doing this ?

Comment: yes, that's the problem. just try. if it works - I'll explain. if it does not - I dont know myself )

Comment: @harshtuna can you take a look at the code ?I've tried it couple of times but I couldn't do it.
I know I should try to learn and try by myself but I need this code to work as fast as possible  ,it would be great if you could say how exactly I should change this

Comment: add `createNewGraph(lowX, highX, frequency, file);` at the end of your "actionPerformed" method. You're changing max/min X in Plotter class, it has no effect (and should not have) on max/min X in Graph class

Comment: @harshtuna thank you 
now I've set lowX and highX with textfield values but I don't have anything to put for file 
what should I put for that ?

Comment: @harshtuna I've added this line  but no graphs get drawn anymore 
    try {
     createNewGraph(minVal, maxVal, frequency, null );
    } catch (GraphArgumentsException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

Comment: you need to replay `graph.addEquation(equation);` for each or your active equations. The code is a terrible mess to be honest. Read some good book on MVC and Java basics (lot's of them). And "Clean Code" by Robert C Martin.